# Help Recording fingerstyle guitar over original song

Tags: recording, fingerstyle-guitar

So I play fingerstyle guitar but I can't really sing that well. So I want to record my fingerstyle playing along with the voice from the original song in the background cause otherwise it sounds too repetitive during the verse where it's the same lick played over and over. I can't figure out how I can do this, so How would I go about doing this ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: it's not clear what you mean. What "original song"? Something recorded by another artist? A piece you write and a friend sang on? And what exactly is repetitive? Your guitar part? the voice?  please form your question more clearly so we can try to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see, what you're meaning, but the problem is that you can't extract separate instruments from a mixed (or already mastered file). However if the part you're talking about is singing only you can try to mix in your recorded guitar. If there is some kind of subby SFX in that part, you can try to suppress it using a dynamic EQ or multiband compressor on lows (you still might affect the vocals though), but if the whole band is playing, you can't filter the vocals out. So ask somebody to record the vocals and then mix them the way you wish. If you try to put the mastered song in background then it will sound messy, however you can eliminate both high and low frequencies with hipass and lowpass filters, make the sound quieter, add a reverb and put it in background but then the vocals will not be audible.